# Parsing and reordering cells content in Python

Tags: python, parsing

Total Newbie question:

I have an excel file and would like to obtain separate two letter acronyms from cells in a column.

It looks like

**Cake_Flavour**

fb&ms  yt/id

ju ny&cd

What I would like to do is to be able to separate the content of each of those acronyms into either a list or whatever structure in python, or just replacing them in different columns

So that at the end I would have

1    fb   ju

2    ms   ny

3    yt   cd

4    id

I have read the documentation but I get stucked with the unicode parsing since I am unable to get rid of the & and the /  or eve to split the different acronyms.

Any tip? please?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You will generally get higher-quality answers if you show code you've tried and have more specific questions about how such code is not working to your expectations.

Comment: Nothing to do with `xlrd`. Tag removed.

Comment: I don't see the relationship between the input and the output groupings. How did you get four groups out of those two cells?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to split out all words of length 2 or more. Then filter out the ones that are longer than two letters.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = u'fb&ms yt/id a bc def ghij'
>>> t = re.findall(ur'[a-zA-Z]{2,}', s)
>>> t
[u'fb', u'ms', u'yt', u'id', u'bc', u'def', u'ghij']
>>> [x for x in t if len(x) == 2]
[u'fb', u'ms', u'yt', u'id', u'bc']
>>>
```

How to transpose the pieces:

```
>>> row1 = [u'fb', u'ms', u'yt', u'id']
>>> row2 = [u'ju', u'ny', u'id']
>>> zip(row1, row2)
[(u'fb', u'ju'), (u'ms', u'ny'), (u'yt', u'id')] # wrong, missing tail
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.izip_longest(row1, row2))
[(u'fb', u'ju'), (u'ms', u'ny'), (u'yt', u'id'), (u'id', None)]
>>>
```

Assuming a variable number of rows:

```
>>> rows = [[u'fb', u'ms', u'yt', u'id'], [u'ju', u'ny', u'id']]
>>> list(itertools.izip_longest(*rows))
[(u'fb', u'ju'), (u'ms', u'ny'), (u'yt', u'id'), (u'id', None)]
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, John. I like your response but Is there any way I could just get rid of the characters like '&' '/' in between the strings. For what I saw the str.replace doesn´t work in the unicode and when I tried to encode it, it doesn´t work either. Sorry for not placing the code.

Comment: @noque: I have showed you how to get rid of the guff so that you are left with a list of 2-letter strings. `str.replace` is not useful here (1) you have `unicode`, not `str` (2) replacing what with what?? Why were you trying to encode it?